# Switch from .btn-group to .btn-group-vertical when a mobile device is used

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

I want to implement a bootstrap button toolbar as demonstrated on [getbootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups-toolbar) with an additional behavior: all button groups should switch automatically to vertical mode when a mobile device is used.

The most appropriate solution in my opinion looks like this:

```
.myClass {
    @media (max-width: 760px) {
        &:extend(.btn-group-vertical all);
    }
    @media (min-width: 761px) {
        &:extend(.btn-group all); 
    }
}
```

Unfortenately the code doesn't work. As far as I understood only classes in the same media scope can be extended this way.

Is it possible to solve the issue without using JS?

Comment: By looking at how all these `.btn-group-vertical` styles [are defined](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.5/less/button-groups.less#L140-L196), I think no, there's no way (not counting simply copy-pasting everything from there  to your `.myClass`). (Also notice that even w/o `@media` problem it would have to be `extend all` not just `extend`).

Comment: Too bad! Indeed I  forgot the `all` keyword in `extend`, edited my question.

Comment: I tried to make a fiddle for you, I think there wont be an non-js option. You could create a second div with visible-xs class and the main div with an hidden-xs class. https://jsfiddle.net/9ymkx2u1/

Comment: The behavior has to be responsive, therefore I would need a window resize event handler which is responsible for switching the classes.. but that isn't a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can make your own vertical button group. Add the custom class of `.btn-vertical` (or whatever you want to name it) to a `.btn-group`.

You technically only need the below CSS but when the button group changes to a vertical orientation you'll be left with the first button left borders and last button right borders rounded, which is visually unappealing. See jsfiddle for full CSS.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .btn-vertical {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .btn-vertical > .btn,
  .btn-group > .btn {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
  }
  .btn-vertical > .btn,
  .btn-vertical > .btn-group,
  .btn-vertical > .btn-group > .btn {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .btn-vertical > .btn-group > .btn {
    float: none;
  }
  .btn-vertical>.btn+.btn,
  .btn-vertical>.btn+.btn-group,
  .btn-vertical>.btn-group+.btn,
  .btn-vertical>.btn-group+.btn-group {
    margin-top: -1px;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .btn-vertical>.btn:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  .btn-vertical>.btn:first-child:not(:last-child) {
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  }
  .btn-vertical>.btn:last-child:not(:first-child) {
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  }
  .btn-vertical>.btn-group:not(:first-child):not(:last-child)>.btn {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  .btn-vertical>.btn-group:first-child:not(:last-child)>.btn:last-child,
  .btn-vertical>.btn-group:first-child:not(:last-child)>.dropdown-toggle {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  }
  .btn-vertical>.btn-group:last-child:not(:first-child)>.btn:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
  }
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
.btn-group.btn-group-lg .btn {
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="media-change">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg btn-vertical">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Sample</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn">Sample</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Sample</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Sample</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Sample</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Sample</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wel, if he chooses to ignore those borders (which *is* visually noticeable with default Bootstrap theme as well as with any other theme having rounded toolbar buttons) then this thing could be simplified to just something [like this](http://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/pen/KpEaqm?editors=110). But I don't think it's the case.